# Do While loop Practice /w User Input

Tags: c#, while-loop, user-input, do-while

I am writing a program for class and need some advice on how to get it working. I have a program that calls for the user to input the price of an item. Once they enter the price for the first item then it asks them for the next price. The problem is that I need it in a do-while loop. I am trying to get the total price for the items entered after each instance of the while loop. I know i could use an array or list but the assignment doesn't call for this. 
Any advice would be helpful.

Here is the code for the do while loop.

```
public static void Main()
    {


        double cost;
        int Items;
        string counter;
        string value;
        string more;
        double newtotal;
        int loopcounter = 0;

        //item cost
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Online Store");
        Console.WriteLine("How many items are you buying?");
        counter = Console.ReadLine();
        Items = Convert.ToInt32(counter);

        do
        {
            // buying items

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the cost of your item one by one");
            value = Console.ReadLine();
            cost = Convert.ToDouble(value);
            newtotal = +cost; 
            loopcounter++;
        }

        while (loopcounter < Items);
```

Comment: Side note, it should be `newtotal+=cost` the way you have it now sets the total to be cost, not adding to the variable

Answer (score 0):

write below code after newtotal = +cost; statement into do while   : Console.WriteLine("your total amount : {0} ",newtotal);

Answer (score 0):

newtotal=+cost; is wrong
instead type newtotal+=cost;

Move

```
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the cost of your item one by one");
```

out from the loop since you don't have to tell the buyer to enter one by one again and again...

Good keep it up